# How a Spring MVC\Boot controller have to return a list of images to the front end that will handle it via AJAX?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am finding some difficulties trying to return a list of images using Spring (I am work on a Spring Boot application but I think that it is the same thing using Spring MVC).

So basically in the past I developed a controller method that return a single image to my front-end, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getAccomodationMasterImageById",
                method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getAccomodationMasterImageById(Long accomodationId) throws DataAccessException {
    log.debug("getAccomodationMasterImageById START");

    InputStreamResource result = null;
    result = accomodationMediaService.getAccomodationMasterImageById(accomodationId);

    log.debug("getAccomodationMasterImageById END");

    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}
```

The image is represented by an **InputStreamResource** object that is returned and rendered by the browser.
It works fine, the user call the resource from the browser via a GET HttpRequest and the controller method return to the browser the image that is rendered.

Now my problem is that I have to implement a new controller method that return a **list of images** instead a single image, so I tryed to do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getListAccomodationImagesById",
                method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getListAccomodationImagesById(Long accomodationId, Boolean isMasterImageIncluded) throws ServiceException {

    log.debug("getListAccomodationImagesById START");

    List<InputStreamResource> result = accomodationMediaService.getAcccomodationImageListById(accomodationId, isMasterImageIncluded);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);

    log.debug("getListAccomodationImagesById END");
}
```

The first problem is that at this line I have an error (before the compilation):

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
```

It seems that **ResponseEntity.ok()** method can't accept a **List** as input parameter (as done for a single image). Why?

In addition to it I am thinking that maybe this strategy to return a list of images is wrong because:

It have to serve a PHP controller that have to show the images. Until I have a single image I can simply call the URI associated to the first controller method and the image is shown in the place where the it is called.

But when I have to retrieve a list of images these images have to be displayed with a specific logic (so I think that it is better that the list of images are retrieve by JQuery and then is JQuery that implement the visualization logic).

So, what is the standard solution to return a list of images from the controller to the front end that will retrieve it via an AJAX call handled by JQuery? Maybe is better to return each image into a byte array? So can I return an array of byte array? (each element represent a single image in the list).

What is the smartest solution to do it?

Comment: What is the return type of `getListAccomodationImagesById`? What would be the return type of `ResponseEntity.ok(result);`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis getListAccomodationImagesById() return aList<InputStreamResource> object. The ResponseEntity.ok(result) returns a BodyBuiler object, why? I think that I am missing something...

Comment: No. What is the return type of `public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getListAccomodationImagesById(..)`? The return type of `ResponseEntity.ok(result)` is definitely not `BodyBuilder`. Check again.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ahhhhh !!! Ok I found the error that prevented the compilation, my getListAccomodationImagesById() have to return a ResponseEntity<List<InputStreamResource>> object and not a single ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> as I had. My doubt now it: what the front end will retrieve? How can I interate (using JQuery or something like this) on these multiple images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By list do you mean a zip file which contains images? At the end of the day you're controller is going to return a response over Http. It can't really return more than one response for a request without using web-sockets or something.

The response message can be interpreted however you see fit, so it can contain images 1 after the other, or a zip file. For instance an array of bytes and in your headers you could give the locations of where the images start and end. But I would recommend not returning many images in one response. The client will have more trouble caching the results as opposed to individual URI's.

I would suggest you borrow from REST principals and return a JSON response which contains hyperlinks to all the individual images, and then the client can follow those links and grab the images. If the client wants to download all the files then a zip file would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you have solved the issue. That compilation error on ResponseEntity.ok(result) is because you have stated Response as a single entity 'InputStreamResource', but are trying to return a list of entities.